# Different databases in one transaction

Tags: c#, transactions

I'm using the `TransactionBlock` code for a web application that stores the connection string in config.

Until now, I was only required to write to a local db, and therefore, this code worked. However, I now need another data access method, to write to another database using a different connection string.

I've created a new connection string in my config file, but I'm not sure about how to call this and swap it out.

The skeleton code I have so far is:

```
  public class TransactionBlock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly bool _mFirstTransactionBlock = false;
    private bool _mDisposed = false;

    public TransactionBlock(string connectionStringConfigKey = null)
    {
        if (connectionStringConfigKey != null && CurrentTransaction != null)
            throw new Exception("Can't create a new transactionBlock with a specific connectionstring if you are already within a block.");

        // Open a connection if we haven't yet already          
        if (CurrentTransaction == null) // we don't have a transaction yet so create one:
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); // Create a new connection object for the connection string.
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                // Severity 20 errors are returned when there are connection
                // problems, so we only retry if the severity is 20.
                // Don't worry about deadlock errors in here - we're just connecting
                // to the database, not running anything which could be deadlocked.
                if (ex.Class != 20) throw;
                // Clear connection pool of all connections related to the given connection string.
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(conn);
                // Try to open the connection once again, catching any error.
                try { conn.Open(); }
                catch { conn = null; }
                // If 2nd attempt failed, throw original exception.
                if (conn == null) throw;
            }
            CurrentTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            _mFirstTransactionBlock = true;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (_mFirstTransactionBlock)
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_mFirstTransactionBlock)
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }

    private void Dispose(bool commit)
    {
        if (_mDisposed)
            return; // committed and cleaned up already.

        try
        {
            var transaction = CurrentTransaction;
            var connection = transaction.Connection; // taking a reference to the connection object as rollback will set it to null;

            if (commit)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            else // rollback the transaction if it hasn't been commited.
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }

            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }

            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        finally // ensure that regardless of connection exceptions, the state is set to disposed.
        {
            // remove current transaction from context.
            CurrentTransaction = null;
            _mDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    private static SqlTransaction CurrentTransaction
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentContext.GetItem<SqlTransaction>("__Transaction");
        }
        set
        {
            CurrentContext.SetItem("__Transaction", value);
        }
    }

    public static SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return CurrentTransaction.Connection; }
    }
    public static SqlTransaction Transaction
    {
        get { return CurrentTransaction; }
    }

    private static string connectionString;
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString ?? "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ServiceLogger.LogError("Database: Creating SQL Connection. Can not find connection string. Nothing will work until this is resolved.");
                    throw;
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                    ServiceLogger.LogError("Database: Creating SQL Connection. Can not find connection string. Nothing will work until this is resolved.");
                else
                    ServiceLogger.LogInfo(String.Format("Database: Creating SQL Connection. Connection string: {0}", connectionString));
            }
            return connectionString;
        }
    }

    #region CurrentContext Helper class
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class for easy access to the appropriate context containers.
    /// </summary>
    private static class CurrentContext
    {
        public static T GetItem<T>(string key) where T : class
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                return (T)HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return (T)CallContext.GetData(key);
            }

        }
        public static void SetItem(string key, object value)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                CallContext.SetData(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the application name to the connection string, but only if it is missing. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    /// <returns>Modified connection string</returns>
    private static string AddApplicationNameIfMissing(string connectionString)
    {
        if (connectionString == null)
            return null;
        // If the connection string hasn't already been configured with an application name,
        // then add one (assumes the application name is not 1st element, as unlikely to have a leading ';').
        if (connectionString.IndexOf(";Application Name=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            return connectionString;

        // TODO: if this turns out to be too slow to perform on each query then caching connection strings should be added.
        // take site name if run from a website or webservice otherwise take process path.
        string appName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName ?? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
        return connectionString += string.Format("{0}Application Name={1}", connectionString.EndsWith(";") ? "" : ";", appName);
    }

    private interface IStructuredParam
    {
        DataTable ToDataTable();
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateSpCommand(string sql)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sql)) throw new ArgumentNullException("sql");

        SqlTransaction tran = CurrentTransaction;
        if (tran == null) throw new NullReferenceException("CurrentTransaction");

        SqlConnection conn = tran.Connection;
        if (conn == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Connection");

        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        if (cmd == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Command");

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        return cmd;
    }
    public void AddParameter(SqlCommand cmd, string name, SqlDbType type, int size, object value, bool isOutput)
    {
        var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p.ParameterName = name;
        p.SqlDbType = type;
        p.Size = size;

        if (value == null)
            p.Value = DBNull.Value;

        else if (type == SqlDbType.Structured)
            p.Value = ((IStructuredParam)value).ToDataTable();

        else
            p.Value = value;

        p.Direction = isOutput == false ? ParameterDirection.Input : ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    }

    public void ExecuteAndMapReader(SqlCommand command, params Action<IDataReader>[] mappingMethods)
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows && mappingMethods != null && mappingMethods.Any())
                        mappingMethods[i](reader);
                }
                i++;
            } while (reader.NextResult());
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `TransactionBlock` doesn't seem to be a native .NET class. Is it from an assembly your code references? If so, post its code so we can understand what its constructor does. Welcome to SO, btw :)

Comment: Thanks Eric, made a modification to the original post.

Comment: I edited (twice, sorry) your post so that the problem returns to the question. Anyways, it seems that there is another SqlTransaction registered in your current HTTP Context. Is there another instance of this TransactionBlock being called in your page?

Comment: Yes, so I have several methods that are doing selects on a local database, then the update needs to happen in another database, on a different server. Hope that makes sense, and thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I think I understood the problem, but the way you asked was misleading :) The exception wasn't thrown at `using`, but at `.Commit()`, which leads to `TransactionBlock.Dispose(true)`, which then leads to the `CurrentTransaction`already registered in your page, and is not yet initialized. I don't think you can use this class _as is_ for this purpose.

Comment: I guess the dirty way would be to replicate TransactionBlock as TransactionBlock2, change the key name, and then call this instead

Comment: Still wouldn't work, since it would still get the current transaction from the HttpContext. Unless you were to change that logic as well.

Comment: Although the entire concept of treating transactions in such a high layer cringes me beyond relief.